# Hidden event being shared with google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

Some spam email managed to create a hidden reoccurring event in my google calendar and it's being shared with outlook ([www.hotmail.com](http://www.hotmail.com)) and my iPhone.

On my iPhone, I was able to delete the series and it disappeared.

On hotmail, I can't seem to do anything to it.

I know its coming from the shared google calendar because I removed the calendar from hotmail and it disappeared, and then re-appeared when I added it again.

How do I find this in google and delete so I'm not forever reminded that "poste italien" is delivering something tonight at 2:10am?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, after much fiddling, I:

- exported my calendar from gmail
- looked at the text.ics and found the date the event was created (2 years ago!)
- went to my calendar in gmail and found the event on that date and deleted it (and the series)
- removed the calendar from hotmail
- reimported/resubscribed the calendar

And at that point it did not show up any more.   hurrah.